# Connecting to SAPHANA from Spark

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to execute query using spark sql on SAP HANA via JAVA code. On calling any action on the data frame object, I am getting  java.io.NotSerializableException.In below piece of code when `df.count();` is invoked, NotSerializableException is thrown.

```
public class SaphanaTest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void call() {

        SparkConf sparkconf = new SparkConf().set("spark.master", "local[*]");

        SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(sparkconf);
        HiveContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
        options.put("url",
                "jdbc:sap://<IP>:30015/system");
        options.put("user", "SYSTEM");
        options.put("password", "Saphana123");
        options.put("dbtable", "SYSTEM.TEST1");

        DataFrame df = sqlContext.load("jdbc", options);

        df.registerTempTable("temp");
        df = sqlContext.sql("select * from temp");

        long count = df.count();
        sc.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SaphanaTest test = new SaphanaTest();
        test.call();
}
}
```

Error stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" **org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable  at**
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:315)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:132)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1893)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1766)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$toLocalIterator$1.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$anonfun$$collectPartition$1(RDD.scala:900)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$toLocalIterator$1$$anonfun$apply$30.apply(RDD.scala:902)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$toLocalIterator$1$$anonfun$apply$30.apply(RDD.scala:902)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)   at
>   scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:29)
>     at com.impetus.saphana.SaphanaTest.main(SaphanaTest.java:48) **Caused
>   by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sap.db.jdbc.topology.Host
>   Serialization stack:**
>     - object not serializable (class: com.sap.db.jdbc.topology.Host, value: 172.26.52.54:30015)
>     - writeObject data (class: java.util.ArrayList)
>     - object (class java.util.ArrayList, [172.26.52.54:30015])
>     - writeObject data (class: java.util.Hashtable)
>     - object (class java.util.Properties, {dburl=jdbc:sap://172.26.52.54:30015, user=SYSTEM,
>   password=Saphana123,
>   url=jdbc:sap://172.26.52.54:30015/?system&user=SYSTEM&password=Saphana123,
>   dbtable=SYSTEM.TEST1, hostlist=[172.26.52.54:30015]})
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anonfun$getConnector$1, name:
>   properties$1, type: class java.util.Properties)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anonfun$getConnector$1,
>   )

Any pointers?
After doing research over google, I found one suggestion to make the connection properties serializable. But I have no idea of how to make it serializable in spark.

Appreciate help on this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Note section from this [Blog](http://www.saphanacentral.com/2016/09/calling-hana-views-from-apache-spark.html) post resolved my issue, you may try as well:

> Note: I’ve tested Spark using the recent SPS12 version of the Hana JDBC Driver (ngdbc.jar)  against a SPS10 & SPS12 system and both seem ed to work fine.  Older versions of the driver give the following error in Spark: ‘ org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sap.db.jdbc.topology.Host’